# Trocar quebra de linha "\n" por "\r\n" em RichTextBox

Tags: c#, quebras-de-linha, richtextbox

Tenho uma `RichTextBox` que precisa contar as quebras de linhas como `"\r\n"`, mas ela está contando como `"\n"`.

Exemplo:

> "Olá, (O usuário aperta <kbd>Enter</kbd>)mundo!"

A `RichTextBox` interpreta assim:

```
"Olá," + "\n" + "mundo!"
```

E eu preciso:

```
"Olá," + "\r\n" + "mundo!"
```

Eu tinha feito o seguinte, para que na hora que eu salvar o texto da `RichTexBox`, as quebras ficassem como `"\r\n"`: Mando o texto da `RichTexBox` para um array de strings chamado `TextoTraduzido` (No caso você pode ir salvando os textos no array), e:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (TextoTraduzido.Length); ++i)
{
    string TextoTraduzidoSeparado = TextoTraduzido[i].Split(separadores, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    TextoTraduzido[i] = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, TextoTraduzidoSeparado);
}
```

Isso resolveu o problema no começo, mas depois reparei que também preciso que a quebra de linha fique como `"\r\n"` enquanto o usuário está digitando.

O texto digitado fará parte de um código hexadecimal, não pode conter mais nem menos caracteres. "\r\n" são dois caracteres e "\n" é apenas um. Por exemplo, se eu digitar um texto com 6 caracteres e uma quebra de linha, meu `label` com `RichTextBox1.Text.Length` vai contar como 7 em vez de 8. Até se eu copiar e colar o texto da `RichTextBox` para outro editor de texto, o texto ficará com menos caracteres, e preciso desses valores no formato correto.

Não há uma forma de trocar o caractere de quebra de linha da `RichTextBox`? Ou então, qual seria a melhor forma de substituir o `"\n"` por `"\r\n"` enquanto o usuário digita?

Comment: Porque precisa de substituir enquanto o utilizador digita? Qual o objetivo?

Comment: @JoãoMartins, editei a pergunta. Dá uma olhada lá por favor

Comment: Certo, então bastaria substituir o caracter "\n" quando fosse buscar o valor da `RichTextBox`, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi trocando a `RichTextBox` por uma `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

Faça a alteração com uma das sobrecargas do método [String.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Quando precisar alterar a quebra de linha:

```
string TextoComQuebrasTrocadas = SeuRichTextBox.Text.Replace("\n","\r\n");
```

̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶i̶r̶e̶t̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶:̶
̶

```
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶T̶e̶x̶t̶.̶R̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶(̶"̶\̶n̶"̶,̶"̶\̶r̶\̶n̶"̶)̶;̶
```

̶
̶*̶*̶C̶a̶s̶o̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶i̶r̶a̶ ̶u̶s̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶n̶t̶r̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶s̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶o̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶T̶e̶x̶t̶C̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶ ̶K̶e̶y̶P̶r̶e̶s̶s̶:̶*̶*̶
̶

```
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶p̶r̶i̶v̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶v̶o̶i̶d̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶_̶K̶e̶y̶P̶r̶e̶s̶s̶(̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶s̶e̶n̶d̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶K̶e̶y̶P̶r̶e̶s̶s̶E̶v̶e̶n̶t̶A̶r̶g̶s̶ ̶e̶)̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶{̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶/̶/̶ ̶S̶a̶l̶v̶a̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶i̶ç̶ã̶o̶ ̶a̶t̶u̶a̶l̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶s̶o̶r̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶i̶ ̶=̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶S̶t̶a̶r̶t̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶T̶e̶x̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶T̶e̶x̶t̶.̶R̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶(̶"̶\̶n̶"̶,̶ ̶"̶\̶r̶\̶n̶"̶)̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶/̶/̶A̶t̶u̶a̶l̶i̶z̶a̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶i̶ç̶ã̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶s̶o̶r̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶S̶e̶u̶R̶i̶c̶h̶T̶e̶x̶t̶B̶o̶x̶.̶S̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶S̶t̶a̶r̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶i̶;̶
̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶ ̶}̶
```

Comment: Não deu muito certo... Coloquei no TextChanged e ao digitar algo como "Testando 123", aparece "321 odnatseT" por causa da atualização constante...

Comment: @ANDREYMOURADASILVA Se você trocar o texto dentro do evento de texto o cursor não se desloca. Tem que compensar a posição manualmente.

Comment: @ANDREYMOURADASILVA Fiz uma edição compensando da posição do cursor.

Comment: Agora o cursor se desloca, mas o "\n" não está sendo substituído por "\r\n".

Comment: Estive lendo os fóruns sobre Visual Studio e descobrir que o `RichTextBox` não permite a terminador de linha diferente de `\n`. Mas você pode a qualquer momento obter uma uma `string` com substituição do terminador de linha.